# I dont know how to turn a toggle transformation to just a hide/show with no animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, toggle

I have a slide layout that works the way I want. I don't know how to change the toggleSlide into a simple hide show on click. I created a container with two links that slide in other containers. I need to change the functionality not to slide but just appear and disappear on click. I do not know how to change the function.

HTML

```
<div class="modhidden">Here I am !

<!--<a href="#" class="modslide">Update</a>-->

  <a href="#" class="modslide col-xs-12 left-btn btn btn-primary">Update</a>

</div>

<div class="modhidden2">Here I am AGAIN!

<!--<a href="#" class="modslide2">Update</a>-->
  <a href="#" class="modslide2 col-xs-12 left-btn btn btn-primary">Update</a>

</div>

<div class="modleft">Left panel

<a href="#" class="modslide">Show ONE</a>

<a href="#" class="modslide2">The other ONE</a>

</div>

<div class="modclear"></div>
```

CSS

```
.modleft, .modhidden, .modhidden2 {
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
    height:350px;
}

.modhidden, .modhidden2 {
    width:100%;
    z-index:2;
    position:absolute;
    right:-1000px;
    background:#f90;
    color:#000;
}

.modleft {
    width:100%;
    float: left;
    height:350px;
    background: pink;
    color: #000;
}

.modclear {
    clear:both;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.modslide').click(function(){
    var hidden = $('.modhidden');
    if (hidden.hasClass('visible')){
        hidden.animate({"right":"-1000px"}, "slow").removeClass('visible');
    } else {
        hidden.animate({"right":"0px"}, "slow").addClass('visible');
    }
    });

    $('.modslide2').click(function(){
    var hidden2 = $('.modhidden2');
    if (hidden2.hasClass('visible')){
        hidden2.animate({"right":"-1000px"}, "slow").removeClass('visible');
    } else {
        hidden2.animate({"right":"0px"}, "slow").addClass('visible');
    }
    });
});
```

JSFIDDLE

https://jsfiddle.net/galnova/jgyt1svb/

Comment: something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/jgyt1svb/1/

Comment: Amazing yes!!! How did you just look at that and know!?

Comment: awesome. just comes with experience :)

Comment: Can you recommend any references or books so that I can pick apart syntax better. I knew the answer was in front of me but I could not sift it out.

Comment: I would just suggest writing lots of code. maybe peruse the answers here and see how people do stuff. and try answering questions. that's how I learn, I haven't read any books or anything. there is always the [jquery api docs](https://api.jquery.com/) that you can read but I think people learn best with practice.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you use only one class instead of two. Instead of modslide and modslide2, just use modslide. Also, instead of adding/removing classes to keep track of state, try jquery's toggle() function.

```
<div class="modhidden">Here I am !

<!--<a href="#" class="modslide">Update</a>-->

  <a href="#" class="modslide col-xs-12 left-btn btn btn-primary">Update</a>

</div>

<div class="modhidden">Here I am AGAIN!

<!--<a href="#">Update</a>-->
  <a href="#"  col-xs-12 left-btn btn btn-primary">Update</a>

</div>

<div class="modleft">Left panel

<a href="#" class="modslide">Show ONE</a>

<a href="#" class="modslide">The other ONE</a>

</div>

<div class="modclear"></div>


.modleft, .modhidden {
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
    height:350px;
}

.modhidden {
    width:100%;
    z-index:2;
    visibility: hidden;
    position:absolute;
    background:#f90;
    color:#000;
}

.modleft {
    width:100%;
    float: left;
    height:350px;
    background: pink;
    color: #000;
}

.modclear {
    clear:both;
}

.visible {
    visibility: visible;
 }


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.modslide').click(function(){
         $(this).toggle(0);
    });
});
```

Seems like this would be allot easier to maintain since there's only one function to update. Also, probable more performant (I haven't tested this) since you don't have the overhead of adding/removing classes from the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

I removed the animation and toggle the visibility on each.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.modslide').click(function(){
    var hidden = $('.modhidden');
    if (hidden.hasClass('visible')){
        hidden.removeClass('visible');
    } else {
        hidden.addClass('visible');
    }
    });
    
    $('.modslide2').click(function(){
    var hidden2 = $('.modhidden2');
    if (hidden2.hasClass('visible')){
        hidden2.removeClass('visible');
    } else {
        hidden2.addClass('visible');
    }
    });
});
```

```css
.modleft, .modhidden, .modhidden2 {
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
    height:350px;
}

.modhidden, .modhidden2 {
    width:100%;
    z-index:2;
    visibility: hidden;
    position:absolute;
    background:#f90;
    color:#000;
}

.modleft {
    width:100%;
    float: left;
    height:350px;
    background: pink;
    color: #000;
}

.modclear {
    clear:both;
}

.visible {
    visibility: visible;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modhidden">Here I am !

<!--<a href="#" class="modslide">Update</a>-->

  <a href="#" class="modslide col-xs-12 left-btn btn btn-primary">Update</a>
  
</div>

<div class="modhidden2">Here I am AGAIN!

<!--<a href="#" class="modslide2">Update</a>-->
  <a href="#" class="modslide2 col-xs-12 left-btn btn btn-primary">Update</a>
  
</div>

<div class="modleft">Left panel

<a href="#" class="modslide">Show ONE</a>

<a href="#" class="modslide2">The other ONE</a>

</div>

<div class="modclear"></div>
```